# Server(PHP) to Local Machine(Python) request

Tags: python, php

I have a php web server

In my local machine i wrote python code to send its private ip(device ip), wifi mac address & public ip (ie. routers ip address in my case my phone) via api. when the the python program hit a api written on the server, php will store the addresses in database.

so the server has the addresses of the local machine.

there are some data in the local machine which it need to send to the server. but i can't send it by hitting api from python to the server because the requirement is the server needs to pull data from client machine when required (will do manually by web user).

so is there any way where server can send request to the python code(written in local machine) with the help of device ip, routers public ip, device mac address.

i know that i can use websocket to do this, but is there any other way??

can i write api in python and the server hit the api when needed, its just my thought i don't know much about networking

Comment: If the server needs to pull data from the client, when does this happen? Is it an any time the server wants to? Or as part of the running of the python app on the client

Comment: There will be a webpage that display the local device list and users of that page will click a button like 'Get Data' and the server should pull data from that machine

Comment: So if the data pull can be requested at any time for no apparent reason known to this client. You would have to basically write a web server to sit on all the client machines. Its not too big a thing to do, but I would not want a server on my PC that I cannot control, and have no idea how secure it is and no idea how easily is can be hacked

Comment: there will be already some python programs running on that local machine so i don't want to run a web server on that local machine

Comment: I didnt say put a web server on the client. I meant you will have to write a little web server, or whatever you want to call it. It will have to be something that is sitting there ALL THE TIME listening on a port for an incoming request using a standard or propriatary protocol, waiting to be asked to service a request. Basically what a web server does. Or any server come to that

Comment: i can write a python socket to listen on a port eg- 8010, for example my device ip is 192.168.0.1 and routers ip is 48.01.163.01 so how can i request to 192.168.0.1:8010

Comment: You have to request to the WAN IP and then Port forward your router so anything coming in on 8010 gets forwarded to the `192.168.0.1` machine where something is listening on port 8010. But that program (whatever its written in) has to be running all the time. _If it looks like a server and it quacks like a server, its probably a server_ :)

Comment: Yes i can do port forwarding in router, but is there another way to do this forwarding in the api, like in header file or something

Comment: The address 192.168.0.anything is a private address and cannot be directly addressed from the internet. Its a security thing. So the only way to get from somewhere on the internet into your machine is port forwarding of some sort